# Edit FSX CFG in Visual Basic

Tags: vba, visual-studio-2010

I have been searching for weeks for some sort of idea on how to do this with Visual Basic but have found nothing.
Basically, I want to modify sections of a .cfg file in Flight Simulator X, such as aircraft.cfg without having to recreate and replace the file.

Is it possible at all? If so, does anyone have an idea on how to do it?

I am using Visual Basic

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Those files are perfectly editable without the use of such programs. And I'm not entirely sure you should ask this here.

Comment: I know I can edit them in Notepad etc. That's fine. I want to edit them in a program I am creating in VB. If not here, where?